# How to save all text from Ace editor in WT?

Tags: javascript, c++, html, ace-editor, wt

So I have embedded an Ace editor in a WT project and loaded a copy of the Ace.js file into it as a test to see how it looks. The load went fine, so now I tried to save it, and I noticed that my save function is not being called. After debugging this for a while, I noticed that my save function does not get called if the file I am trying to save is larger than 70000-80000 characters, and gets called fine and passes the data along if the file is smaller. How can I get around this limit when trying to save large files? The code that I am running in the WT project can be seen below, with more details on how to embed it here [Using ACE with WT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15832798/using-ace-with-wt)

```
WText *editor;

MyClass::MyClass(const WEnvironment& env)
: WApplication(env)
{
wApp->require("lib/src/ace.js");
// A WContainerWidget is rendered as a div
editor = new WText("function(){\n hello.abc();\n}\n", root());
editor->setInline(false);
editor->resize(500, 500);

std::string editor_ref = editor->jsRef(); // is a text string that will be the element when executed in JS

std::string command = 
  editor_ref + ".editor = ace.edit(" + editor_ref + ");" +
  editor_ref + ".editor.setTheme(\"ace/theme/monokai\");" +
  editor_ref + ".editor.getSession().setMode(\"ace/mode/javascript\");";

editor->doJavaScript(command);    

JSignal <std::string> *jsignal = new JSignal<std::string>(editor, "textChanged");
jsignal->connect(this, &MyClass::textChanged);

WPushButton *b = new WPushButton("Save", root());

command = "function(object, event) {" +
  jsignal->createCall(editor_ref + ".editor.getValue()") +
  ";}";

b->clicked().connect(command);
}

void MyClass::textChanged(std::string incoming)
{

}
```

Now, with the above code the textChanged function will be called when the Save button is pressed. However if a large file is loaded, I used the function below, and replace "function(){\n hello.abc();\n}\n" with a call to it.

```
std::string MyClass::ReadFile(std::string path)
{
std::ifstream in(path, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
if(in)
{
  std::string contents;
  in.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
  contents.resize(in.tellg());
  in.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
  in.read(&contents[0], contents.size());
  in.close();
  return(contents);
}
throw(errno);
}
```

As mentioned previously, I loaded Ace.js, which is about 15,000 lines in length. This caused my save call to fail. Though I am sure that any other file over 80,000 chars will cause it to fail as well. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Probably max-request-size in wt_config.xml needs to be increased. It's 128K by default.

Comment: I am not currently using a wt_config.xml in my project, I will try adding it and setting the max-request-size.